# Brainzilla IQzilla 2 test question - coloured squares in a 3x3 grid

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

**I need your help solving this question**

I've been trying to solve this question for half an hour, but I can't find a pattern. Can someone please help me? I'm very curious about the solution.

We have to figure out which square(A, B, C, D,..., H) we have to put in the lower right corner of the image on the left based on some logic.

Source: [Brainzilla](https://www.brainzilla.com/)

[image: Problem]

Answer (score 6):

I think the answer is

> A

Explanation:

> If we number the little squares 1,2,...,9, then summing the positions of the non-blank little squares of the same color gives three new positions, which in all three cases happen to be distinct and don't exceed 9. Making those gray is consistent with the first two rows, and corresponds to A in the third one.

Comment: Oh, nice! Thanks, I've been wondering about the solution to this one!

Answer (score 1):

I am confident the answer is

> C

Reasoning:

> [image: reasoning]

Comment: Your answer makes sense, but the answer on the website
is different. I checked which answer increases the score.  
It could be a mistake or the question has multiple answers.
If you want to check the answer you can go to: https://www.brainzilla.com/iq-tests/iqzilla-2/ question
number 22 and just check which answer increases the score.I can't hide the answer in a comment.